# Dock a Canvas in its parent

Tags: wpf, canvas, dock

How can I "dock" a canvas in its parent?

I have a UserControl that contains a canvas inside.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUC"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d"              
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <MyCanvas x:Name="myCanvas" 
        Height="???" 
        Width="???{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" >
    </MyCanvas>
</UserControl>
```

I use `Width` and `Height` properties of this custom canvas inside. And need that that properties be always "bind" to the parent Container.

Comment: so that your UserControl is always the same size of the container above? can you paste a bit more xaml?

Comment: @user109134: the UserControl should be docked also its parent - a form. so its dimensions are variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                               AncestorType=UserControl, 
                                               AncestorLevel=1},
                Path=ActualWidth}"
```

Same goes for height

Answer (score 2):

If you don't set the `Width` and `Height` properties in the `Canvas` it will occupy all the space available in the `UserControl`. Here's a simple example:

[MainWindow.xaml]

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="500" Height="500"
        x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow">
    <Grid Background="Blue">
        <local:UserControl1 />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[UserControl1.xaml]

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Background="Green">
<Canvas Background="Red" />
```

If you run this app, you'll see that the background color is red, meaning that the `Canvas` takes all of the space made available by the `UserControl` (and its parent `Grid`). You can also resize the window - the `Canvas` will follow.

Comment: as I said, I use `Width` and `Height` properties, so I need to set it explicitly, if not they will be NaN, and I can't use ActualWidth/Height instead.

Comment: In that case the solution above works. Another option is to simply name your parent UserControl and use regular Element Binding (e.g. Width="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=ActualWidth}").

Comment: if a Canvas is in a Grid, removing Width and Height does not expand the canvas...

Answer (score 1):

```
<MyCanvas x:Name="myCanvas" 
     Width ="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=Width}" 
     Height="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=Height}">
</MyCanvas>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.